# Unable to connect to socket.io server

Tags: nginx, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have NGINX set up to route requests to example.com to nodejs server on port 3000 which serves the front end and example.com/api to nodejs api server on port 3001.

I try to connect to the socket on port 3001 like:

```
const socket = openSocket('example.com/api');
```

But I get an error in the console:

```
polling-xhr.js:265 POST https://example.com/socket.io/? 
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MWPLGiL 404 (Not Found)
```

It looks like socket.io is still trying to connect to only example.com.
Any idea why the /api is being ignored? I need this to go to example.com/api since that server is configured to handle the socket connections. Would be grateful if some one can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding the following in NGINX config:

```
 location ~ ^/(api|socket\.io) {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 900s;
}
```

Sorry for asking the question without digging in more. Hope this helps some one else.

Comment: Don't sorry, I faced same problem and your solution helped me.
Thanks